# Not being able to stop at exception when using consecutive stream.flatMap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream

When debugging my code in IntelliJ IDEA I can't stop at an exception in certain cases when consecutive `flatMap` methods are used on a stream. Instead of stopping at exception, it stops in API's [ReferencePipeline#flatMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#271) method at line 271, with frames stack not showing the exception at all. Here's the simplest example possible:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class AssertTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(0, 0, 0),
            Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1),
            Arrays.asList(2, 2, 2)
        )
            .stream()
            .flatMap(a -> test1(a).stream())
            .flatMap(a -> test2(a).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    private static List<List<Integer>> test1(List<Integer> ints) {
        return Arrays.asList(ints);
    }
    private static List<List<Integer>> test2(List<Integer> ints) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Here's what I see in my IDE when I run the code in debugger:

[image]

If I comment out the line that says `.flatMap(a -> test1(a).stream())`, then it stops at the exception as intended. The same occurs with assertions (replace `throw new RuntimeException()` with `assert false` and run with `-ea`).

This issue concerns only the debugger: after the program crashes on exception, the stack trace contains the right place where the exception originated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at mypkg.AssertTest.test2(AssertTest.java:23)
    at mypkg.AssertTest.lambda$main$1(AssertTest.java:16)
    at mypkg.AssertTest$$Lambda$2/14008398.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at mypkg.AssertTest.main(AssertTest.java:17)
```

Is this a bug? If so, is it mentioned anywhere? If not, where should I report it: Jetbrains, Oracle? Or is this the correct behavior?

Comment: You've tried putting a breakpoint in the test method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you put a breakpoint on `throw new RuntimeException()`, then yes, it stops at that line before throwing an exception, but after the exception is thrown it stops inside the API method anyway.

Comment: @Susei I'd say to contact JetBrains first since this concerns the debugger. If there is missing or deficient information coming out of the debugger interface to the JVM, they'll be able to determine that and forward the information to Oracle.

Comment: Have you tried splitting up the big single line in the main method into multiple lines? Assign the array list to to a variable, assign the result of stream() to a variable, etc. Then try again with the exception breakpoint.

Comment: @EngineerDollery That doesn't change anything since `flatMap()` method is lazy, the actual computation occurs in the terminating method (in this case, `collect()`).

Comment: @EngineerDollery Ah, now I understand what you're saying. But the question is not how to avoid this error-handling, but rather why it happens and whether it should happen or not.

Comment: Yes, but I was interested in seeing if you got the same problem with single lines, showing if it's a problem with a lower library (as it seems to be according to your answer), or if it's just IntelliJ not liking the fluent interface style with closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer I got from a Jetbrains developer after reporting a bug:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126981?replyTo=27-763411

> I can reproduce it only if I set any exception breakpoint to stop only on uncaught exceptions, is this the case?
>
> Your exception is caught and re-thrown inside java, it is a downside
> of streams :( You'll need to stop on caught exceptions as well to be
> able to stop in your code.

Enabling stopping at caught exceptions fixes this for me.